# how to load images in frontend when image path save in backend database server

Tags: flask, ionic-framework, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a image in my windows server in drive C under folder Images and in my database the path of the image is saved as Images/logo.jpg
Now, I want to read the image from the frontend of my app and display it in my app.

I deploy my backend apis in a windows server. I save the image name in my database. but when i call the apis i get the data. Suppose my api url is: 0.0.0.0:5000. And i have my image in c drive Like
**C:\X\Y\images** where my images are stored. How do i display the images in through frontend.

I provided link as **src="0.0.0.0:5000/X/Y/images/{{get from api}}"** but it shows 404 not found.
I have used Ionic(Angular) for the frontend part and flask python as backend.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a new route in Flask to serve the static image files.

```py
@app.route('/images/<path:path>')
def send_image(path):
    return send_from_directory('C:/X/Y/images', path)
```

You can then use `src="0.0.0.0:5000/images/{{image_file_name}}"`.